# Key error because the keyring app may not start properly?

Tags: linux, ssh

I do not get why there is this error

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When it didn't use to. So currently I have to do:

1. Start agent in silent mode

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

2. ssh-add to add my key.

I have checked the autostart app command that runs, which is:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh
```

How do I get it always automatically added when I start my session in Ubuntu Mate 22.04 ?